# escape character &amp; doesn't work for impersonation tag in web.config, asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net

I hope someone has a good answer to this stupid question I have.  I'm trying to use impersonation in my asp.net 3.5 application within the web.config file to connect to my sql server 2008 database so I use:

When I run my app, I get this:

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

Source Error:

impersonate="true" userName="testUser"  password="test(ampersand sign, sorry this forum actually does render it properly)amp;test" />

So basically it posts the password with the actual escape for ampersand rather than the actual ampersand.  This leads me to believe it's processing it as a literal but validating it as xml, unfortunately I can't just use "test&test" in the web.config file because visual studio just won't compile it since it's marked as an error.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue? The same issue is on our costumer's environment, but not on QA. And it is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you miss "&" before amp;